# Error trying to import netCDF4 in python script using chaquopy with android studio

Tags: python, android, netcdf, chaquopy

I am trying to integrate python code into an Android app using Chaquopy with Android Studio.

The Android app is dying on import netCDF4 in the python module.  I am running Android Studio on MacOS and made sure netcdf4 was installed via:

```
 %pip3 uninstall netcdf4
 %pip3 install netcdf4
```

It installs fine.

But Android Studio app dies with:

```
  Caused by: com.chaquo.python.PyException: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'
```

The build.gradle has these components:

```
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.pythoncalledfromandroidstudio"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    python{
        version "3.10"
        pip {
            // A requirement specifier, with or without a version number:
            install "numpy"
            install "netCDF4"
        }
    }
```

But cannot get past the error.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you rebuilt the app after adding netCDF4 to the build.gradle file. If you did, the build would fail, because this package contains native components. This means it would have to be built into a wheel file. If you'd like to try doing this yourself, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi). And if you're successful, please make a pull request so we can add the package to the public repository.

Comment: I was hoping to do a copy paste of a screenshot but will type in the main points of it:

Comment: logcat of build errors: (1) :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements:3 errors (2)Command errored out with exit status 1 (3)Failed to install netCDF4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/.,.,.../netCDF4-1.6.2.tar.gz#...(4)Process 'command 'python3.10'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: I will take a look at the link you provided...

Comment: Stepping through the chaquopy linked page now.  A question if I may:  The document states "Use pip to install the requirements.txt in this directory."  Where in the chaquopy tree does this need to happen?  Also, how to make it happen - "pip3 install requirements.txt" fails.  Just not familiar with this part.

Comment: "This directory" means server/pypi: I'll update the README to be clearer about that. StackOverflow comments aren't very good for extended discussions, so if you have any more questions, please create an issue [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues).

Comment: Thanks for that -- I just realized that about 2 mins ago before seeing your msg above!